# Unity Android save screenshot in gallery

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I use this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class ShareButton : MonoBehaviour {

public void ClickShare()
{
    StartCoroutine(TakeSSAndShare());
}

private IEnumerator TakeSSAndShare()
{
    string timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    Texture2D ss = new Texture2D( Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false );
    ss.ReadPixels( new Rect( 0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height ), 0, 0 );
    ss.Apply();

    string filePath = Path.Combine( Application.persistentDataPath, "Tanks" + timeStamp + ".png" );
    File.WriteAllBytes( filePath, ss.EncodeToPNG() );

    Destroy( ss );


}

}
```

to save screenshot on button press. How can I save it in some folder so it could be found in Android gallery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You need to get the correct path

In your current solution you would be able to find the screenshot in `android/data/com_your_application/files` and you probably want to save it in another place.

To save your screenshot in: `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/`

You can use Unity's [AndroidJavaClass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html?_ga=2.225529434.198314353.1583076481-379777761.1581498721) and [Object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.html?_ga=2.225529434.198314353.1583076481-379777761.1581498721) to get the path:

```cs
    private string GetAndroidExternalStoragePath()
    {
        if (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.Android)
            return Application.persistentDataPath;

        var jc = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Environment");
        var path = jc.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getExternalStoragePublicDirectory", 
            jc.GetStatic<string>("DIRECTORY_DCIM"))
            .Call<string>("getAbsolutePath");
        return path;
    }
```

This will give you the path to the public DCIM folder in Android and you can then pass that path into your `File.WriteAllBytes` call

Remember to set **write permission** to **External(SDcard)** in **Player Settings** for Android.

If you don't want your screenshots to appear in the root of the DCIM folder you can simply append a directory to the path.